# Combine two data frames across multiple columns

Tags: r

Say I have two dataframes, each with four columns.  One column is a numeric value.  The other three are identifying variables.  For example:

```
set1 <- data.frame(label1 = c("a","b", "c"), label2 = c("red", "white", "blue"), name = c("sam", "bob", "drew"), val = c(1, 10, 100))
set2 <- data.frame(label1 = c("b","c", "d"), label2 = c("white", "green", "orange"),  name = c("bob", "drew", "collin"), val = c(7, 100, 15))
```

Which are:

```
> set1
  label1 label2 name val
1      a    red  sam   1
2      b  white  bob  10
3      c   blue drew  50
> set2
  label1 label2   name val
1      b  white    bob   7
2      c  green   drew 100
3      d orange collin  15
```

The first three columns can be combined to form a primary key.  What is the most efficient way to combine these two data frames such that  all unique values (from columns `label1`, `label2`, `name`) are displayed along with the two `val` columns:

```
set3 <- data.frame(label = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "d"), label2 = c("red", "white", "blue", "green", "orange"), name = c("sam", "bob", "drew", "drew", "collin"), val.set1 = c(1, 10, 50, NA, NA), val.set2 = c(NA, 7, NA, 100, 15))
> set3
  label label2   name val.set1 val.set2
1     a    red    sam        1       NA
2     b  white    bob       10        7
3     c   blue   drew       50       NA
4     c  green   drew       NA      100
5     d orange collin       NA       15
>
```

Comment: Also, the names of the output columns are not important.  I can reformat the names as needed.

Comment: What is your question? R's `merge` can take a list of multiple column names.

Comment: Hmm seems like you may be right.  `merge(set1, set2, by = c("label1", "label2", "name", all = TRUE` seems to work.  I was not entering the correct parameters for `all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When thinking of efficiency, you should evaluate the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
(merge(
  setDT(set1, key=names(set1)[1:3]), 
  setDT(set2, key=names(set2)[1:3]),
  all=T,
  suffixes=paste0(".set",1:2)
) -> set3)
#    label1 label2   name val.set1 val.set2
# 1:      a    red    sam        1       NA
# 2:      b  white    bob       10        7
# 3:      c   blue   drew      100       NA
# 4:      c  green   drew       NA      100
# 5:      d orange collin       NA       15
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they're in the same format, you could just rowbind them together and then take only the unique values. Using dplyr:

```
    bind_rows(set1, set2) %>% distinct(label1, label2, name)
```

You just want to make sure that you don't have factors in there, that everything is a character or numeric.